# cmake tests does not compile

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake

I try to run tests onto project directory. my CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (fleetd-test-retranslator)

find_path ( ../
            ../../cashes
)
include_directories( ../ 
../../cashes
../../protocols
)
add_executable (fleetd-test-retranslator test_retranslator.cpp)

enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
if (NOT GTest_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find Google Test Framework!")
endif()
target_link_libraries(fleetd-test-retranslator GTest::GTest GTest::Main)

set (sources
     test_retranslator.cpp
     ../retranslator.cpp
     ../retranslator.h
     ../slcache.cpp
     )

set(libs
    utils
    core
    cashes
    gtest
    gmock
)
```

but after I try to compile this test I receive an error

```
/home/yrusinov/projects/fleetd-2/cashes/StateCache.h:10: error protocols/Protocol.h: No such file or directory
 #include "protocols/Protocol.h"
                                ^
```

despite of directory is included and file is present ? Where is my error ?

Comment: The include directory should contain `protocols/` **subdirectory** which in turn should contain `Protocol.h` file. Is it true in your case?

Comment: yes, it is true.

Comment: I guess, **full path** to the header is `/home/yrusinov/projects/fleetd-2/protocols/protocols/Protocol.h`, isn't it? BTW, your usage of `find_path` is completely wrong. What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: No, my full path is /home/yrusinov/projects/fleetd-2/protocols/Protocol.h

Comment: Read my first comment carefully: your include directory, which is specified in `include_directories` call, should have `protocols` subdirectory. You have specified `/home/yrusinov/projects/fleetd-2/protocols/` as include directory, but **it has no `protocols` subdirectory**. So the header file is not found. Correct include directory should be `/home/yrusinov/projects/fleetd-2/protocols`, or `../..` relative to the project's source directory.

Comment: @YuriyRosinov: Actually, it was a **wrong review** on [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49146483/3440745): its comment applies to the answer with **only** "thanks a lot" which obviously is not an answer. But your answer post is different: `I set in include_directories ...` makes the post an **actual answer**. And introduction phrase "thanks a lot" in your case means a **credit** to the person who suggested that in a *comments*, which is perfectly OK on Stack Overflow. (Usually credits have a form "Thank to @nickname", but again, your one is OK). You may safely **undelete** your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, I set in include_directories (../ ../../) and all compiles.